# React useContext value is not getting passed from the provider?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I'm trying to pass a value down using `useContext` as below

This is Context.js

```
export const selectedContext = React.createContext();

export const SelectProvider = () => {
  return (
    <selectedContext.Provider value={"Team One"}>
      <Cards />
      <Pies />
    </selectedContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

I'm calling the context in one of the components like so

This is in Card.js (a child in the provider)

```
const value = React.useContext(selectedContext);
console.log(value);
```

When I initialize the value from `React.createContext`, the value is passed down to my component but when I try using the provider it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you get errors in the console ? Because your code structure implies that the `Card` component will try to import from the `Context.js` while the `Context.js` tries to import the Card from `Card.js`. That means you have cyclic dependencies

Comment: Yeah, I sorted that out.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using `React.useContext` like this it's not wire into the `<Context.Provider>`

Please see the docs on who to use `React.useContext` [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext).

It's seems that the `React.useContext` will not work with in the Provider direct component children, so you need to make one more component in between. (like in the docs example)

```
const selectedContext = React.createContext();

const SelectProvider = () => {
  return (
    <selectedContext.Provider value={"Team One"}>
      <Cards />
    </selectedContext.Provider>
  );
};

const Cards = () => {
  const value = React.useContext(selectedContext);
  console.log(value); // will not work

  return (
    <Card />
  );
};

const Card = () => {
  const value = React.useContext(selectedContext);
  console.log(value); // will work

  return (
    <div>My Card</div>
  );
};
```

If you need it to work on the first layer of component you can use `<Context.Consumer>` and it will work within.

```
const selectedContext = React.createContext();

const SelectProvider = () => {
  return (
    <selectedContext.Provider value={"Team One"}>
      <Cards />
    </selectedContext.Provider>
  );
};

const Cards = () => {
  const value = React.useContext(selectedContext);
  console.log(value); // will not work

  return (
    <div>
      <selectedContext.Consumer>
        {({value}) => (
          <h1>{value}</h1> // will work
        )}
      </selectedContext.Consumer>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, but you should "call the context" in the child component of the provider, as the `value` is available in `Provider`'s children:

```
export const SelectedContext = React.createContext();

export const SelectProvider = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <SelectedContext.Provider value={'Team One'}>
      {children}
    </SelectedContext.Provider>
  );
};

const ProviderChecker = () => {
  const value = React.useContext(SelectedContext);
  return <div>{value}</div>;
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <SelectProvider>
      <ProviderChecker />
    </SelectProvider>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit aged-cdn-9r367]

Comment: I'm calling it in the Cards component which is a child component in the provider but it still doesn't work.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: That's not helping, try creating a codesandbox or at least show us how you calling cards and how it is not working.

Comment: You are not calling the Provider as explained in the answer, see https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-star-hd8gb, and you should check the sandbox attached to the answer...